# Cannot save knitted hat on latest Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, safari, winter-bash-2018, mac

When I click the "DOWNLOAD" link on the [Winter Bash hat knitting tool](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com), I get this error message:

> Safari can’t open the page “blob:https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/a0dda976-17cf-4ae3-b012-4658fe7bd012”.
>
> The error is: “The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitBlobResource error 1.)” (WebKitBlobResource:1)

[image: browser screen shot with error message]

I am using MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6) with most up-to-date Safari browser (12.0.2).

I expected a bitmap (maybe PNG format) to be downloaded. Instead, it seems to be some "blob:" protocol that I haven't seen before (but what do I know of these things).

---

When right-clicking on the link and selecting "Download Linked File" the link works and the file is downloaded. It looks like Safari just doesn't know how to open the `blob:` link.

Comment: Same here, I was just digging into this to write up a bug report. Nothing in the console, and (from what I can tell) no request is actually made, so no headers to inspect or anything.

Comment: @TimPost: Indeed, it looks like a link that the browser doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: blob: stands for binary large object, in other words, file data, which might be a bitmap or a png. See https://superuser.com/questions/948738/what-is-the-blobhttp-prefix-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-this for more info about blob links, it surprises me that Safari apparently doesn't support them

Comment: For what it's worth, downloading is working in [Safari Technology Preview](https://webkit.org/blog/6017/introducing-safari-technology-preview/), so we're probably hitting a bug/limitation that'll get fixed in 12.1.

Comment: `document.getElementById('ke-download-link').removeAttribute('target')` makes it work for me. Filing a PR.

Comment: My first thought was: Who on earth would go on a safari with a knitted hat? It’s much too warm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed for Safari on macOS.

[image: iconic "hello" knit]

There is a bug in Safari where opening a blob in a new tab will produce the error you observed.  Funny enough, the reason we have `target` is to mitigate the fact that IE doesn't support the `download` attribute, so helping one browser hurt another.

This fix doesn't carry over to Mobile Safari unfortunately, because (as I only found out after pushing) it doesn't support the `download` attribute or opening blobs in a new tab. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Not sure what we'd want to do there, because we also don't want to navigate.

Comment: I have same issue, I tried with all combination of having `target` or `download` attribute and still same error, any idea?